# Sequence diagram multiple calls to same method from different locations

Tags: uml, diagram, sequence-diagram

I want to create a sequence diagram of my program. 
The code goes like this:

I have a class SFC, this class starts with the method *parseScenario()*. The parseScenario() method is a loop until all elements in a list are looped over. In this loop I call the *parseEntryLine(e)* method, where e is an entry in that list. 
Now my problem occurs.
In parseEntryLine(e) there is an IF statement as follows:

```
if (currentGM.isBrick ()) {
    animateExpr(currentGM);
    //Check if it has a next
    if (currentGM._next != null) { parseEntryLine (currentGM._next); }
    } else {
        //random code
        parseEntryLine(buttonStringClicked);
    }
}
```

How do I model this in a sequence diagram?
I managed to work until this point: 
[image: sequence diagram]

(I realize this might already be a wrong start).

Comment: Generally there's not much point in creating a graph from code. In this case you just need to add `parseEntryLine(buttonStringClicked)` in the else part.

Comment: Can you tell me why? I want to give a high-level view of my system so it is more easy to understand for 'readers'. I have already made a UML class diagram and a system architecture. My explanation of the UML class diagram is quite detailed, and I was thinking of creating the sequence diagram to give more high level clearance

Comment: What do you think yourself is better to read: a complex graph or some lines of code? The difficulties you have expressing code in a graphical way reflect the analogous problems a reader would have. SDs should be used to highlight a certain important sequence, not to overall control flow. At a certain level code is better suited than UML.